# How to check if a cookie is set in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I defined an optional cookie parameter and now want to check if the cookie was set. Unfortunately, the variable does not equal to `None` but to an empty `Cookie` object. How can I check the cookie object if it is set?
Here's how I defined the cookie parameter:

```
@app.route("/graphcall")
def graphcall(request: Request, ads_id: Optional[str] = Cookie(None)):
    if ads_id:
      # Do stuff if the ads_id is set
```

Comment: Hey @guerda i'm not very confident with cookies but this [approach](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#cookies) could work `request.cookies.get()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you tried this via SwaggerUI. Setting Cookie values currently does not work via SwaggerUI due to browser security restrictions.

```
@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(ads_id: Optional[str] = Cookie(None)):
    if ads_id:
        answer = "set to %s" % ads_id
    else:
        answer = "not set"
    return {"ads_id": answer}
```

works perfectly from command line with Fastapi 0.61.0

```
$ curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Cookie: ads_id=foobar"
{"ads_id":"set to foobar"}

$ curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/" -H  "accept: application/json"
{"ads_id":"not set"}
```

Comment: I did test it without swagger, I'm rendering an HTML template. Still the variable always is not None.

Comment: Same situation, did you solve the problem?

Comment: They should highlight this in the docs. This has bite me twice... See the original issue https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/880

Answer (score 1):

For me this works

```
async def setcookie(request: Request, nm: str = Form(...)):
    print("setcookie "+nm)
    response = templates.TemplateResponse("readcookie.html",{"request": request})
    response.set_cookie(key="userID", value=nm)

@app.get("/getcookie/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def getcookie(request: Request,userID: Optional[str] = Cookie(None)):
    if userID:
        print("getcookie "+userID)
    else:
        print("getcookie None")
    return templates.TemplateResponse("showcookie.html", {"request": request, "name": userID})
```

In getcookie I have the cookie set in setcookie.

I follow this approach:

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-cookies/#return-a-response-directly

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand why the `Optional[str] = Cookie(None)` method didn't work.  For me this way worked

```
@router.post('/login')
async def sign_in(
        user_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
        service: AuthService = Depends(),
):
    session = await service.authenticate_user(
        user_data.username,
        user_data.password
    )
    response = RedirectResponse(url='/')
    response.set_cookie('Authorization', value=session['session_id'], httponly=True)
    return response


async def get_current_user(request: Request): 
    try:
        cookie_authorization: str = request.cookies.get("Authorization")
        # some logic with cookie_authorization
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Invalid authentication"
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you put

```
ads_id: Optional[str] = Cookie(None)
```

Try

```
async defer(cookie_token: Optional[std] = Cookie(default=None)):
```

Comment: That type specification `std` should be `str` instead?